# Sdl.dll monogame

Tags: c#, monogame

Вопрос: для чего там эта библиотека?

Она создается в стандартном шаблоне Monogame WindowsGL.

Назначение SDL.dll мне не сильно понятно, если без нее собирать все работает.

Пробовал найти в интернете информацию, пока не нашел.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека нужна для полноценной работы `Tao Framework`. Это фреймворк, предоставляющий разработчикам `.NET` и `Mono` доступ к возможностям популярных библиотек вроде OpenGL и SDL.
MonoGame нуждается:

1. `Tao.Sdl.dll` (который требует нативную
      библиотеки SDL (`SDL.dll`))
2. `OpenTK.dуl` (который требует OpenGL
       для того, чтобы работать, а также
       `OpenAL`)
3. `Libgren.Network`

Comment: не сильно понятно

я не пользуюсь Tao, я вообще понятия не имею что это и в коде у меня нет его использования.

Comment: кажется слегка разобрался